# Merge multiple Excel files into a new Excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I know the question has been asked so many times already, and I have tried to use Google to search the interest but failed to find the correct code. ( Trust me, I am not a taker).

Anyway, the idea is to run a script to merge all Excel files (CAD,GBP,JPY,USD) into a new Excel file (tab shows name "CAD","GBP", "JPY","USD") in the current folder. I have written the following script to merge Excel files, but it does not even work.

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks()

    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim WS              As Worksheet

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "X:\PATH\TO\EXCEL\FILES" 
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
            WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next WS
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "it does not even work" - needs to be explained. Are you running this from Excel or command line?

Comment: This is VBA, not VBScript.

Comment: Hi, neither from Excel or command line. My goal is run from VBscript. Any help, please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one small mistake.

Change:

```
Wkb.Close False
```

To:

```
Wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Here's my full, tested and working solution:

```
Sub CombineWorkbooks()

    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim WS              As Worksheet


    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "X:\PATH\TO\EXCEL\FILES"
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
            WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next WS
        Wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        FileName = Dir()
   Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If this doesn't work for you, please give more detail about the results and/or errors. A list of the file names in the folder would also be helpful.

If this does work for you, please remember to mark this as your answer, so others will know you have your solution. Thanks!